# Defining and Projecting .asc raster files while maintaining that file format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder

I need to preprocess a large number of .asc raster files for use in a species distribution model. The model i am using has the requirements that the raster files used are projected into WGS84 and are of the .asc format. This is causing me a issue as the raster files i have need to be projected into BNG before they can be used in ArcGIS Desktop and because most of the tools in ArcGIS will convert a .asc to a Tiff which means i then have to convert it back at the end.

My current workflow is as follows:

1. Define the projection of the .asc files
2. Project to WGS
3. If this has changed the file type then convert back to a .asc

I am aiming to develop the workflow in ArcGIS Desktop to batch process all of the raster files.

What would be the most efficient (least number of processes/tools used) method to define and re-project the raster files while maintaining the .asc format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do it with a couple of tools and an iterator ending up with ASCII rasters. The image below shows a possible way to run the model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

[image]